# how to prevent element re-rendering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have to show a PDF file on a page and it works well but whenever I open or close the modal the PDF is re-rendered.

```
import { documentActions } from '../_actions'

export default function DocPreview() {
    const document = useSelector(({ document }) => document)
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => dispatch(documentActions.getDocumentContent('someDocId')), [dispatch])

    return <main>
        {document.loaded && <embed src={URL.createObjectURL(document.data)} type='application/pdf' />}
        <button onClick={() => setShow(true)}>Sign document</button>
        <Modal show={show} onHide={() => setShow(false)}>
            <button className='btn btn-secondary' onClick={() => setShow(false)}>Close</button>
        </Modal>
    </main>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the pdf document it's own component and only re render when document changes:

```
const Pdf = React.memo(function Pdf({ document }) {
  document.loaded && (
    <embed
      src={URL.createObjectURL(document.data)}
      type="application/pdf"
    />
  );
});
```

In DocPreview

```
<main>
  <Pdf document={document} />
```

Comment: it didn't work that way, a `return` was missing and it still didn't work but you gave me a good idea and I used `useMemo` so I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: solution: `const Pdf = React.useMemo(() => document.loaded && <embed
    src={URL.createObjectURL(document.data)}
    type="application/pdf"
/>, [document])`